# How to double a char in a string?

Tags: python-2.7

I am trying to write a function that takes two arguments, a string and a letter. The function should then double the number of letter in the string. For example:

```
double_letters("Happy", "p")
Happppy
```

what i have done so far;

```
def double_letter(strng, letter):
 new_word = ""
    for char in strng:
        if char == letter:
            pos = strng.index(char)
            new_word = letter+strng[pos:]
```

But this is giving me the output: pppy

how can i change the function to get the output: Happppy?

Comment: Looks like your logic is off: When the `char` isn't equal to your letter - you aren't doing anything with `new_word` for a start, and then you're always assigning back to `new_word` and not appending...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `string.replace`

```
string = 'happy'
letter = 'p'
string = string.replace(letter, letter + letter)
print string
```

Comment: `letter * 2` is allowed and imho reads more obviously that you want two of the letters

Comment: thnx for the simply answer

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`join`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) and iterate through the characters in your string:

```
def double_letters(word, letter):
    return "".join(2*i if i == letter else i for i in word)
```