# Is there a way to insert an extra "\" into a string in Python?

Tags: python, string

I am trying to turn the regular `'\'` (single backslash) in a file path, which the user inputs in the form of a string, to two backslashes.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: `print(mystring.replace("\\", "\\\\"))` - compare with `print(mystring)`

Comment: That's a backslash \. A slash leans the other way /.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python replace single backslash with double backslash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17327202/python-replace-single-backslash-with-double-backslash)

Comment: Also related: [How to double a char in a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22605967/4518341), [Replace part of a string in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10037742/4518341), maybe [Why do backslashes appear twice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24085680/4518341) and [Windows path in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2953834/4518341)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try the `str.replace`?

```
>>> s = 'C:\\Users'
>>> s = s.replace('\\', '\\\\')
>>> s
'C:\\\\Users'
>>> print(s)
C:\\Users
```

Comment: I edited the code already, but just wanted to mention, don't use `input` as a variable name since it shadows the builtin `input()`.

Answer (score 2):

You do not need any special handling:

```
 a = 'abc\def'
 print(repr(a))
 #'abc\\def'
 print(a)
 #'abc\def'
```

Comment: Note that `'\d'` will be invalid in a future version of Python. You should write `'\\d'` instead. See [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#index-23).

Answer (score 2):

Here is how you can use an `r` string:

```
path = input("Input the path: ")
print(path.replace('\\',r'\\'))
```

Input:

```
Input the path: C:\Users\User\Desktop
C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop
```

Answer (score 0):

Would definitely go with the `.replace()` method:

```
object.replace("\\", "\\\\")
```

Comment: The syntax is wrong. You need to double the backslashes. Anyway this method was [already posted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62925525/4518341).